# Laravel 5 POST routes to index instead of store

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing, restful-architecture

I am working on a Laravel 5 RESTful API that seems not to be routing the POST requests correctly.

This is my routes.php:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function()
{
    Route::resource('messages', 'IncomingMessages');
});
```

And this is my controller:

```
class IncomingMessages extends Controller
{   
    public function index() {
        return "This is index";
    }

    public function store() {
        return "This is store";
    }

    public function update() {
        return "This is update";
    }
}
```

And this is what happens:

- Request `GET mydomain.com/api/v1/messages/`  --> This is index
- Request `PUT mydomain.com/api/v1/messages/1` --> This is update
- Request `POST mydomain.com/api/v1/messages/` --> ***This is index***

This is what `php artisan route:list` returns:

- GET|HEAD : api/v1/messages  : api.v1.messages.index : App\Http\Controllers\IncomingMessages@index
- GET|HEAD : api/v1/messages/create : api.v1.messages.create : App\Http\Controllers\IncomingMessages@create
- POST : api/v1/messages : api.v1.messages.store : App\Http\Controllers\IncomingMessages@store
- GET|HEAD : api/v1/messages/{messages} : api.v1.messages.show : App\Http\Controllers\IncomingMessages@show
- GET|HEAD : api/v1/messages/{messages}/edit : api.v1.messages.edit : App\Http\Controllers\IncomingMessages@edit
- PUT : api/v1/messages/{messages} :api.v1.messages.update ; App\Http\Controllers\IncomingMessages@update
- PATCH : api/v1/messages/{messages} : App\Http\Controllers\IncomingMessages@update
- DELETE : api/v1/messages/{messages} : api.v1.messages.destroy : App\Http\Controllers\IncomingMessages@destroy

So, my question is:

What am I missing? Why is it routing to `index()` instead of routing to `store()`?

NOTES:

- I have disabled "VerifyCsrfToken" in `Kernel.php`
- I am trying the requests using Chromium plugin "Postman".

**UPDATE:**

The problem was adding a trailing `/` to the URL. So, instead of using this URL:

```
mydomain.com/api/v1/messages/
```

I tried with this one:

```
mydomain.com/api/v1/messages
```

and it worked

Comment: Hi brother run this command  **php artisan routes** and show me the result please.

Comment: Hi @ZakariaAcharki, i have edited my question to show what php artisan returns.

Comment: The roots looks fine, are you sure that the request is POST. try to execute this line in console and verify the response :

`$.post( "api/v1/messages", function( data ) {
  console.log( data );
});`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki you gave me the clue. I checked Apache logs and found out that for every POST there was a 301 redirect. I finally realized that I was adding a trailing '/' to the URL. Removing it fixed it.

Comment: I have the same problem, but removing trailing slashes did not do anything...

Comment: @Inigo I discovered the problem by taking a look at the web server's log. I saw there that every POST request was being redirected.

Comment: Yeah, my problem wasn't trailing slashes but the validation that automatically redirected to resource/index. Strange that no validation error is displayed by default. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please, add your solution as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: Thank you for the editing and the suggestion @Alfabravo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was caused by a trailing `/` being added to the URL. So, instead of using this URL:

`mydomain.com/api/v1/messages/`

I tried with this one:

`mydomain.com/api/v1/messages`

and it worked.

I discovered it by taking a look at the server's log. That is how I discovered that POST requests to the URL `messages/` were redirected.

Comment: `PUT mydomain.com/api/v1/messages/` (without passing the id) is redirect index() or listing. Is there option to restrict it?

Comment: @San, in that case you should not use Route::resource(), use Route::put('/api/v1/messages', YourController@yourMethod.

Answer (score 1):

if you are still having this problem and the route is using `FormRequest`

check if there a `authorize` function in it because it will redirect if it returns false