# Laravel POST call returns index() function instead of store()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, http-post, laravel-routing

I'm writing my first app in laravel, it's really nice environment for new laravel developers. To shorten the story: I've created two eloquent models via php artisan commands and created corresponding controllers the same way. One of those is "Members" model, I've created public functions inside the class of the controller, but when I try to POST to the route that should use store() function that route actually uses index() function.

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Member;
use Response;

class MemberController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $members = Member::all();
        return Response::json([
            'data' => $this->transformCollection($members)
        ], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if(! $request->email){
            return Response::json([
                'error' => [
                    'message' => 'Please Provide email'
                ]
            ], 422);
        }
        $Member = Member::create($request->all());

        return Response::json([
            'message' => 'Member Created Succesfully',
            'data' => $this->transform($Member)
        ]);

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $Member = Member::find($id);

        if(!$Member){
            return Response::json([
                'error' => [
                    'message' => 'Member does not exist'
                ]
            ], 404);
        }

        return Response::json([
            'data' => $this->transform($Member)
        ], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if(! $request->user_id){
            return Response::json([
                'error' => [
                    'message' => 'Please Provide user_id'
                ]
            ], 422);
        }

        $Member = Member::find($id);
        if($request->email){
            $Member->email = $request->email;
        }
        if($request->first_name){
            $Member->first_name = $request->first_name;
        }
        if($request->last_name){
            $Member->last_name = $request->last_name;
        }
        if($request->phone){
            $Member->phone = $request->phone;
        }
        if($request->address_one){
            $Member->address_one = $request->address_one;
        }
        if($request->address_two){
            $Member->address_two = $request->address_two;
        }
        if($request->zip_code){
            $Member->zip_code = $request->zip_code;
        }
        if($request->city){
            $Member->city = $request->city;
        }
        if($request->county){
            $Member->county = $request->county;
        }
        if($request->state_region){
            $Member->state_region = $request->state_region;
        }
        if($request->country){
            $Member->country = $request->country;
        }
        if($request->job_title){
            $Member->job_title = $request->job_title;
        }
        if($request->company){
            $Member->company = $request->company;
        }
        if($request->clearance_level){
            $Member->clearance_level = $request->clearance_level;
        }
        $Member->save();
        return Response::json([
            'message' => 'Member Updated Succesfully',
            'data' => $this->transform($Member)
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Member::destroy($id);
    }

    /**
     * @Description Data transform
     * @param $contacts
     * @return array
     */
    private function transformCollection($contacts)
    {
        return array_map([$this, 'transform'], $contacts->toArray());
    }

    /**
     * @Description Data transform
     * @param $contact
     * @return array
     */

    private function transform($contact)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $contact['id'],
            'fname' => $contact['first_name'],
            'lname' => $contact['last_name'],
            'email' => $contact['email'],
            'address' => $contact['address_one']
        ];
    }
}
```

My model is:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Member extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'members';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'phone',
        'address_one',
        'address_two',
        'zip_code',
        'city',
        'county',
        'state_region',
        'country',
        'job_title',
        'company',
        'clearance_level',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];
}
```

My php artisan route:list is:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                           | Name                   | Action                                                 | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                             |                        | Closure                                                |            |
|        | POST      | api/v1/members                | api.v1.members.store   | App\Http\Controllers\MemberController@store            |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/members                | api.v1.members.index   | App\Http\Controllers\MemberController@index            |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/members/create         | api.v1.members.create  | App\Http\Controllers\MemberController@create           |            |
|        | DELETE    | api/v1/members/{members}      | api.v1.members.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\MemberController@destroy          |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/members/{members}      | api.v1.members.show    | App\Http\Controllers\MemberController@show             |            |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/v1/members/{members}      | api.v1.members.update  | App\Http\Controllers\MemberController@update           |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/members/{members}/edit | api.v1.members.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\MemberController@edit             |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | auth/login                    |                        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogin      | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | auth/login                    |                        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postLogin     | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | auth/logout                   |                        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogout     | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | auth/register                 |                        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postRegister  | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | auth/register                 |                        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getRegister   | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | password/email                |                        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@postEmail | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/email                |                        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@getEmail  | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | password/reset                |                        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@postReset | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}        |                        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@getReset  | web,guest  |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Route definition:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function(){       
    Route::resource('members', 'MemberController');
});
```

I tried both ‍`mysite.us/api/v1/members` and `mysite.us/api/v1/members/`

they both return `index()` on `POST`.

Comment: show us your blade as well. Make sure your form is of  `post` method

Comment: I'm using POSTMAN chrome plugin to post it via this URL, I have same exact model called Contacts, on my other Laravel install and it runs smoothly. And yes <form method="post"> is in the blade form as well.

Comment: in postman check if you are sending form-data and not (for example) json

Comment: Nah buddy, I'm sending x-www-form-urlencoded, as I've stated in the previous comment I'm doing the same process on my other app and it works.

Comment: Do you use `echo Form::open(array('url' => 'api/v1/members', 'method' => 'post')` or are u hardcoding `method="post"`?

Comment: For testing purposes I'm using POSTMAN chrome plugin, POST-ing all those fillable fields via x-www-form-urlencoded to that URL, I've used it before and it always delivered, now it returns index() function instead of store on POST call even tho Laravel says it should go for store().

Comment: Can you show your route/resource definition?

Comment: There you go: 
`Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function(){
    Route::resource('members', 'MemberController');
});`

Comment: Can you show us your form definition please?

Comment: Buddy, I already told you I'm not using form, but POSTMAN chrome plugin with x-www-form-urlencoded option, and it worked on other models with same definitions. POST option returns index instead of store.. I don't know what else to tell you.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem has been solved by @Arangor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31304958/1886270)

Quote:

> The problem was adding a trailing '/' to the URL. So, instead of using this URL:

```
mydomain.com/api/v1/messages/
```

> I tried with this one:

```
mydomain.com/api/v1/messages
```

> and it worked

Answer (score 0):

add CSRF field to your form

ex:

```
<form id="form-login" class="m-t form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/login">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
```