# Some unclear behavior of the Laravel routing

Tags: json, laravel, post, routes, multipartform-data

I am a little bit confused in my current situation.
I have a routes like this:

```
Route::get('clients', 'ClientController@index');
Route::post('clients', 'ClientController@store');
```

And the index() and store() methods in the controller.
This is the part of the RESTful API so I want to accept requests with the json.

So here is my POST JSON request:

```
> POST /api/clients/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: dfs.test
> User-Agent: insomnia/5.14.6
> Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjYrejBPZE5CbnRXcmg3cEZnOWorbGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieVNjK1NlVGt3R0lmY3hkWG1ybXBuQWxBdlBRSnBiUlNZOGp1WU5rVWw2RFhWVXlNWExIZGNSUUQ0ZXBuMUZxb3g1RVIxWEhITWdPd2hiaVlCc3NKZUE9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImE1OWUxMWNiNzJiMDRkYTVmYjUwYzUwNjZhODM5NWVkNmJjYWZkODE2ZDk0ODI2NzY5MmQyNmRlNmYzYmQxNWEifQ%3D%3D; dfs_session=dnGZsrMSwbkA7szMR5oAJsTIlAkJW98w1htDFJjW; laravel_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsImNzcmYiOiI3YUZpVk9BS0pJNkVYZzJJS1pWSU85WWxYVWtaZ3FjSFVnZEJ0eGI5IiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNTE4ODY5OTQzfQ.aQp6Nm37QyTIJgIUuHd0T_8-2Sap5WqcS8WM6K5G3Zs
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: application/json
> Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjJhZjU5NmNlY2VmOGE5ZWNiZjgwZWM3NWRmNTlkOTAyMzZhZDRhM2I5ODA2YjAxMDMzMmVmZDFmMDA4YzcyNmNjMTFkZmUxM2Q2Y2ZlM2E5In0.eyJhdWQiOiI0IiwianRpIjoiMmFmNTk2Y2VjZWY4YTllY2JmODBlYzc1ZGY1OWQ5MDIzNmFkNGEzYjk4MDZiMDEwMzMyZWZkMWYwMDhjNzI2Y2MxMWRmZTEzZDZjZmUzYTkiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTg3OTQ2NzQsIm5iZiI6MTUxODc5NDY3NCwiZXhwIjoxNTUwMzMwNjc0LCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbImFwaS1tYWluLXJlYWQiLCJhcGktbWFpbi1kZWxldGUiLCJhcGktbWFpbi11cGRhdGUiLCJhcGktbWFpbi1jcmVhdGUiXX0.zpe2rYfZxAB6xiKasQbEvt2D_4TbGp9xjSeLWNklhd2YUwDIgyOubQUMz4dAOcfjbuxQnG5h3Mc2LaidIdvMiXt53nuE9I8_9Kq9Sx6GCZ4vRpWiXAATe5d7oDDXxp6147Rtkd9O0io0Wcc0yhtgRRvSwxAzYbOnnENR3cICsNymEVhNJr5yrH2xIxhfsJrgWaFuPCpslCava53AuwO7Urm2CXPImXIP5dVqqn8qOGA_-LkJTE3S9yagmU5-3niubLqlpoGA55yv-fcYZo90sFX68VM4PSIh1xGjX_3K9Tot_BFfCAOFDoYujv51dpf94uecFHnzUyulcLXYstGImGJTWnfRIiqA7pExo3bkZ8F1PUXOiYW8N9yzwe_6_2wpzUEJqemk7mEesF7mzk5rYldix3ZWh2wxu_crgD6faRiNpbsG3m0zSPNfLMny0ckYTnPyibrsVPklndJWHaoe1yrroD_jFoRe31LQh3iQFhIxNOVIACAwkvXK1Y5w98KsqbE8lyS2JWtA-xiHYjVmLsJsp6G_N9OFVDl-iX4Hn57H_-AtbsV6iy6Vi9I40v4zx9r7U3GkFRedYhu8rUxa2bTtScwfxOzJCav3R__sS1cJiMwa8EYliPAEenkCN5e8iP-4tWm8Qpmn0kV5vgQzABKsZVulY5KWdkHFDu0G1-M
> Content-Length: 17
| {
|   "asd": "asd"
| }
```

If I send above request from some REST client like Insomnia or Postman with "Content-type: application/json" OR with "application/x-form-www-urlencoded" Laravel will route me to the index() method. But I defined it for the GET request! How it happens?

Also if I send some post data with the "multipart/form-data" header Laravel will route to the controllers store() method.

So Laravel routes POST requests only with the multipart/form-data headers?
If yes, how to accept the json body in Laravel when it routes to the incorrect method?

My Laravel version is 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, and after hard googling for a couple days here is the solution: [Laravel 5 POST routes to index instead of store](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31304958/1886270)